# Noether momentum for the electromagnetic field in Susskind's Theoretical Minimum

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, noethers-theorem

In [Susskind's Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Special_Relativity_and_Classical_Field_T/ukjTDQAAQBAJ), he derives an expression for the Noether momentum of an electromagnetic field. He defines Noether momentum to be the notion of momentum that is the conserved quantity associated with translation symmetry. The equation is given in (11.24) with a slight modification in a footnote. The final version is:

\begin{equation}
  P_x = \int E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^n}\, dX^n
\end{equation}

This follows typical notation: $E$ is the electric field, $A$ is the vector potential, and $X$ are spacetime coordinates. Latin subscripts and superscripts denote spatial coordinates. Summation convention applies.

If you're confused about what exactly this equation says, I share your confusion. Here's exactly what Susskind says in the book:

$$P_x=\int dx E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial x}\tag{11.24}.$$

Then, in a footnote:

> "Because these integrals reference one space component at a time, we’ve written $dx$ instead of $d^3x$. A more precise notation for the integrand of Eq. 11.24 might be $dX^n E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^n}$. We’ve decided on the simpler form, where $dx$ is understood to reference the appropriate space component."

Why would $P_n$ be an integral over just the $n$ spatial component? This would mean e.g., that there's a different conserved momentum in the $x$-direction for every pair $(y,z)$. I would have expected this to be a volume integral over all spatial components. That is

\begin{equation}
  P_n = \iiint E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^n}\, d^3X,
\end{equation}

in which case there would be a single conserved momentum component for each dimension.

The former statement is stronger than the latter statement. If the former is true, then the latter is also. However, the latter being true does not necessarily imply the former being true.

He actually changes his equation later to be a volume integral over the Poynting vector by saying that $-\int E_m (\partial A_n / \partial X^m)\,dX^n=0$ (he uses integration by parts and assumes $\rho=0$ so that $\nabla\cdot E=\partial E_m/\partial X^m=0$). The final equation is

\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{P} = \iiint (\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B})\, d^3x.\tag{p.380}
\end{equation}

But, I believe, this can be rewritten

\begin{equation}
  P_n = \iiint (\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B})_n\, d^3x,
\end{equation}

in which case it's inconsistent with his previous equation that used an integral over just one spatial dimension. Did he just make a mistake in his earlier integral? Or, am I missing something or making a mistake somewhere?

In case it's helpful, he works up to the first integral by starting with the expression for the conserved quantity in the discrete case:

\begin{equation}
  Q = \sum_i \Pi_i f_i(q),\tag{p.378}
\end{equation}

where $\Pi_i$ is the canonical momentum conjugate to the coordinate $q_i$ and $f_i(q)$ is a function of all coordinates that multiplies the infinitesimal in the coordinate transformation:

\begin{equation}
  \delta q_i = f_i (q) \delta.
\end{equation}

He used a gauge transformation to zero out the time-component of the vector potential so that

\begin{equation}
  \Pi_m = \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial t} = -E_m.\tag{11.16}
\end{equation}

Finally, he performs the transformation:

\begin{equation}
  \delta A_m = -\delta \left(\frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^m}\right),
\end{equation}

so that

\begin{equation}
  f_i(q) = -\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial X^i}.
\end{equation}

He then uses these results with the equation for $Q$ in the discrete case to write an integral over one spatial dimension without saying why it's only over one spatial dimension.

Comment: Did you transcribe the first equation correctly? If you are using the summation convention, you have a free index on the left, but not the right side of the equation. If you are not using the summation convention your indices still don't make sense...

Comment: Hm, it's possible I didn't. Here's exactly what he has: $P_x=\int dx E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial x}$. Then, in a footnote: "Because these integrals reference one space component at a time, we’ve written $dx$ instead of $d^3x$. A more precise notation for the integrand of Eq. 11.24 might be $dX^n E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^n}$. We’ve decided on the simpler form, where $dx$ is understood to reference the appropriate space component."

Comment: OK... so the "n" index isn't summed? Has he introduced the summation convention yet?

Comment: He has introduced it. If I combine those 2 statements I get $P_x=\int dX^n E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^n}$. I think the summation rule would say that every combination of $n$ and $m$ are summed here, but I'm not sure... But then how does he decide this is $P_x$? That equation seems wrong to me. Another reason I think this should be the volume integral I wrote in the 2nd equation.

Comment: I looked at the Kindle version of the book It is just wrong. Or, a little more charitably, it is just incredible confused notation. I added an answer to this effect.

Comment: If this is not already in the errata, you should let susskind know.

Comment: @hft I searched around but did not find an errata. I sent an email to Susskind (or rather his administrative contact, which is the contact I found) pointing out the error and suggesting an errata be added to theoreticalminimum.com.

Comment: Nice. Hope they rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The final version is:
> \begin{equation}
>   P_x = \int E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^n}\, dX^n
> \end{equation}
>
> This follows typical notation: $E$ is the electric field, $A$ is the vector potential, and $X$ are spacetime coordinates. Latin subscripts and superscripts denote spatial coordinates. Summation convention applies.
>
> If you're confused about what exactly this equation says, I share your confusion. Here's exactly what Susskind says in the book:
>
> $$P_x=\int dx E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial x}\tag{11.24}.$$
>
> Then, in a footnote:
>
> > "Because these integrals reference one space component at a time, we’ve written $dx$ instead of $d^3x$. A more precise notation for the integrand of Eq. 11.24 might be $dX^n E_m \frac{\partial A_m}{\partial X^n}$. We’ve decided on the simpler form, where $dx$ is understood to reference the appropriate space component."

Unfortunately, the above-quoted footnote is misleading and confusing. I would call this whole discussion in this section of the book confusing with respect to the meaning of the integration region and the notation.

The expressions for *momentum* **should** be integrated over the volume element, as you suspected. The book is just wrong, or using some really horrible notation.

The expression in Eq. 11.25 is similarly wrong/misleading. However, the equation *below* Eq. 11.25 is correct:
$$
\vec P = \int d^3 x \vec E \times \vec B\;.
$$

---

Below I present what I hope to be a less-confusing development along with same lines as Susskind.

The Lagrange density for electromagnetism in the $A_0=0$ gauge is:
$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\vec{A}}^2 - \frac{1}{2}(\vec \nabla \times \vec A)^2\;,
$$
therefore, the canonical momentum *density* is:
$$
\vec \Pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\dot{\vec{A}})}
=\dot{\vec{A}}\;.
$$

Therefore, the Noether-conserved-charge *density* (which turns out to be the momentum *density*) associated with the symmetry of the Lagrangian under rigid translation
$$
A_i(\vec x, t) \to A_i(\vec x - \vec \epsilon, t) =A_i - \vec \epsilon\cdot\nabla A_i\;,
$$
where $\vec \epsilon$ is a constant is:
$$
\vec \pi= -\sum_i \Pi_i\vec\nabla A_i=\sum_i-\dot{\vec{A_i}}\vec \nabla A_i
=\sum_i E_i\vec \nabla A_i\;.\tag{1}
$$

And, therefore, the Noether-conserved momentum is:
$$
\vec P = \int d^3x \sum_i E_i\vec \nabla A_i\;,
$$
since you get the momentum by integrating the momentum density over the volume.

If you want to put this in terms of the $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ fields, in free space where $\rho=0$, we can add zero in the form:
$$
\vec \nabla \cdot E = 4\pi \rho = 0\;,
$$
to see that
$$
\vec P_j = \int d^3x \sum_i E_i\nabla_j A_i + 0
$$
$$
= \int d^3x \sum_i E_i\nabla_j A_i + \int d^3 x \sum_i A_j \nabla_i E_i
$$
$$
= \int d^3x \sum_i E_i\left(\nabla_j A_i - \nabla_i A_j \right)
$$
$$
=\int d^3x \left(\vec E \times \vec B\right)_j
$$